# Differential in Maxwell velocity distrubution derivation

Tags: calculus, probability, derivatives, probability-distributions, partial-derivative

I'm trying to understand how Maxwell velocity distribution is derived.

I'm using [this](https://portal.tpu.ru/departments/kafedra/tief/method_work/method_work2/lab1/LabsMechMolecFiles/ModT-04.pdf) PDF as a base. It's in Russian, the closest English analogue is Chapter 2 of [this](http://www1.udel.edu/pchem/C444/spLectures2011/kt_02102011_p2.pdf) PDF.

I'm stuck on this derivation and equality:

[image]

*(Russian text is: Variables Vx, Vy, Vz are independent. Let's derive both equations with respect to Vx... Thus...)*

Function $f$ accepts a velocity vector, $v$ is magnitude of the velocity.

If I need to show the equality from the last line, I need to somehow get differential of magnitude from first equation's derivative. But how?

**P.S**: I do not understand why we can derive $f(\vec{v})$ (vector function) by means of $v$ (magnitude) in the first line. And where we get $\partial v$ from in the first equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there is a typo at the russian reference since the notation $f'(\vec{v})$ is typically used to represent the Jacobian matrix of a multivariable function $f$, which in this case have dimension 3x1 while $\frac{\phi'(v_x)}{\phi(v_x)}$ is a scalar, so the dimensions are mismatched. Very likely the russian author wanted to write $f'(v)$ that would be equivalent to $\Omega(\nu)$ of the english reference, which I will use from now on.

The confusion seems to stem of fact that the symbol $\Omega$ (as well as the russian $f$) is overloaded with two meanings. One as a function of spatial coordinates
$$\Omega(v_x, v_y, v_z) = \Omega(\vec{v}) \tag{1}$$
and the second one as a function of the speed $\nu = \sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2}$
$$\Omega(\nu) = \Omega\left(\sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2}\right) \tag{2}$$
alternated when conveniently.

This is arguably not good math notation since it leads to unnecessary ambiguity. It becomes clearer what is going if we write $\Omega$ as a function of speed (2) as lowercase omega instead, namely $\omega$. For that consider
$$\Omega :\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R} : (v_x, v_y, v_z) \mapsto f(v_x)f(v_y)f(v_z)$$

$$\omega :\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{R} : (v_x, v_y, v_z) \mapsto \nu(v_x, v_y, v_z)$$
$$\omega \circ \nu : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R} : (v_x, v_y, v_z) \mapsto \omega(\nu(v_x, v_y, v_z))$$

Then simply name $\omega \circ \nu$ as $\Omega$. So
$$\Omega(v_x, v_y, v_z) = \omega(\nu(v_x, v_y, v_z))$$

Note that $\nu$ is acting like a one-way change of coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (spatial) to $\mathbb{R}$ (radial).

Now looking to the notation
$$\frac{d \ln \Omega(\nu)}{d \nu}$$
with the proposed notation we can infer that the author actually means something like
$$\frac{d \left( x \mapsto \ln (\omega(x)) \right)}{dx}$$
in Leibniz' notation, or
$$\left(\ln \circ\ \omega\right)'$$
in Lagrange's notation. Again overloading symbols by also using $\nu$ to mean the independent variable of the function $\omega$. That is, it means the derivative with respect to $x$ of the funtion
$$\ln \circ\ \omega : \mathbb{R}_{> 0} \to \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto \ln (\omega(x))$$
While by writing
$$\frac{\partial \ln \Omega(\nu)}{\partial v_x}$$
it means the partial derivative with respect to $v_x$ of the function
$$\ln \circ\ \omega \circ \nu : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R} : (v_x, v_y, v_z) \mapsto \ln(\omega(\nu(v_x, v_y, v_z)))$$

Thus, for every point $(a, b, c) \in \mathbb{R}^3$, by the chain rule it follows that
$$\frac{\partial \ln \Omega(\nu)}{\partial v_x} \biggr\rvert_{(a, b, c)} = \frac{d \left( \ln \circ\ \omega \right)}{dx} \biggr\rvert_{\nu(a, b, c)} \frac{\partial \nu}{ \partial v_x} \biggr\rvert_{(a, b, c)}$$
in Leibniz' notation, and

$$\frac{\partial \ln \Omega(\nu)}{\partial v_x} (a, b, c) = \left( \ln \circ\ \omega \right)' (\nu(a, b, c)) \frac{\partial \nu}{ \partial v_x}(a, b, c)$$

in Lagrange's notation.

Comment: But why can we put magnitude function inside and have the same expression on the right?

Comment: I am afraid that this has not much to do with math but is rather derived from a physical hypothesis of the problem. In fact, on page 4 of the english reference the author states: "An assumption regarding the nature of this distribution: the gas is isotropic such that the direction of particle movement does not affect the properties of the fluid. In this sense, the velocity distribution is effectively dependent on the magnitude of the velocity." That is, it is indifferent looking at the velocity distribution as a function of spatial coordinates or as a function of radial coordinates.

Comment: So, why is if gas is isotropic then f(vector) == f(magnitude(vector))? From what exact isotropy statement does it come?

Comment: It is an **assumption** of the physical model in question. I am unable to answer you that since I am no physicist. This is a _mathematics_ Q&A site and this is the farthest I am able help regarding to mathematics. To find an answer to this particular _physical_ question you will be best helped in [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).